# Protecting other directories in a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a website which was made with wordpress.
Back then, I did not know how to add new 'backoffice pages' to wordpress, because I didn't know much about WP.
So, I created a custom backoffice in codeigniter, and placed the main folder on the /public_html

That means, that on the public_html there are the directories like:

- wp-admin
- wp-content
- wp-includes
- backoffice - This is the CodeIgniter

The owner of the website is always updating his WP. And recently, the 'backoffice' (CodeIgniter directory) got infected with malicious code.

How do I prevent this to happen? Is there any way to deny changes done to the codeigniter files?

This is the htaccess of the 'backoffice'

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Your problem is not wordpress related. You just need to set up proper permissions on your directories, so that the web-server can't write to `backoffice`.

Comment: Ok, but I would still need help with this. Would it need to be done with the .htaccess from the public_html or the 'backoffice' directory ? I updated my post with the backoffice .htaccess

Comment: Sorry, it's the first time this happens and I wasn't really understanding. I think I understand you now, but I'm not sure how to handle with this. I've been searching for a while and I set the 'backoffice' directory with Permissions 555. But I'm not sure if this is the right one to apply.

Comment: Read on web-server security. Google is your friend.

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing that.